# How to go to the view of a subcategory from category view in yii ...?

Tags: php, yii

I wanted to add an icon "view Subcategory" under the operations menu along with "Edit", "update", "Delete" etc. in the category view, on clicking the "view subcategory", it will display the admin view of all the subcategories inside that category, so far i have added a controller action to that option and i am getting the category id from that, i don't know how to pass all the subcategories details into the admin view of subcategories, i would appreciate any help.
I have added the option view Subcategory in the view of category like :

```
array('label'=>'View SubCategory', 'url'=>array('/subcategory/viewsub', 'id'=>$model->categoryid)),
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add an extra icon for viewing subcategory then you need to change cbuttoncolumn in cgridview and in that need to add imageUrl and give path for image.

```
array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        'template'=>'{view}{update}{size}{subcategory}{delete}',
         'buttons'=>array
              (

            'subcategory' => array
            (
                'label'=>'Subcategories',
                'imageUrl'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/subcat-icon.png',
                'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("/subCategory/admin", array("id"=>$data->subcatid))',
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

add this code in place of CButtonColumn array. please change paths etc according  to you requirement

==================== Edit===========================================
 Admin action of subcategory ---

```
 public function actionAdmin($parent_id)
{
    $model = new SubCategory('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    if(isset($_GET['SubCategory']))
        $model->attributes=$_GET['SubCategory'];

    $this->render('admin',array(
        'model'=>$model,'parent_id'=>$parent_id
    ));
}
```

================== in side admin.php in cgridview in subcategory view folder ==================

change you cgridview dataprovider line like this. pass parent_id to search function

```
'dataProvider'=>$model->search($product_id),
```

=== inside model of subcategory========================

Change search function header like this.. accept parameter.

```
public function search($parent_id)
{
//all other code here
//add condition like this

// in you subcategory table if you are using parent_id as parent category id or what ever change according to that


   if(isset($parent_id)){
        $criteria->condition = 't.parent_id='.$parent_id;
    }
```

Comment: ..i have just added the menu "view subcategory" in the view and called an action for it, where i am getting the id of the category..
..but how would i pass the subcategory data from the controller to the admin view of subcategories...?

Comment: do you need to show subcategories for this category???. I hope what you requirement is that user click on subcategory icon and gets all subcategories for parent. if yes then you need category id else please let me know.

Comment: exactly..when a user views a category there will be an option to view subcategory under the operations menu, on clicking it, the user will get all the subcategories under that category...

Comment: ok then this should be array("parent_id"=>$data->id) and then in subcategory admin get this parent id and use it to build a query where this parent category id is used in where clause. Are you facing some difficulty in this??

Comment: so right now are you seeing all subcategories inside admin view of subcategory??

Comment: ok one way to achive this im posting in my answer. there can be multiple ways

Comment: i have updated the answer it is very easy to implement. please change you code and hopefully you will get desired result. you have to change three places and according to your db structure. let me know any issue3

Comment: i did exactly what you asked, i have created another search function `custom_search` in my model and passed the criteria condition but it still does not work. I am getting `The "dataProvider" property cannot be empty.` error

Comment: have you implemented it with search

Comment: yes, i have created another function in my model `custom_search` where i put the criteria condition

Comment: and did you call that function in view as specified above. Because I did exactly same with my code and it is working fine. cna you post your code?

Comment: I have created same custom_search function in my Model and called it from cgridview from View and assigned an ID from controller. It works for me. Please check carefully if your cat_id is properly going to custom_search function.

Comment: yes it is going in my custom_search function, i have checked it, but i guess the query is not running, i am getting the error: `The "dataProvider" property cannot be empty.` what might be wrong?

Comment: have you added complete code in model custome search. I dont see this code in you model function.
return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
   'criteria'=>$criteria,
  ));

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need [Yii CGridView add custom button](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/593/yii-cgridview-add-custom-button/)

[Using CButtonColumn to customize buttons in CGridView](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/106/using-cbuttoncolumn-to-customize-buttons-in-cgridview/)